# Rotation of AVL tree nodes does not work

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am trying to write AVL tree in python but rotation doesnt work becase I cannot swap "self" node with any other. Is there any way to fix it? I think that doing this in Java or C way is not correct...

```
class Sentinel(object):
     value = left = right = None
     height = -1

sentinel = Sentinel() #singleton of sentinel node

class Node:    
def __init__(self, data, left=sentinel, right=sentinel, height=0):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    self.height = height

def addNode(self, data):
    if self.data == data:
        #return when node duplicated
        return
    isLeft = self.data > data
    child = self.left if isLeft else self.right

    if child is sentinel:
        if isLeft:
            self.left = Node(data)
        else:
            self.right = Node(data)
    else:
        child.addNode(data)
        if abs(child.right.height - child.left.height) == 2:
            print("Rebalancing after inserting", data)
            ''' Then we need to balance a subtree'''
            if data < child.data:
                rotation = self.rotateLeft if isLeft else self.rotateRight
            else:
                rotation = self.doubleRotateLeft if isLeft else self.doubleRotateRight
            rotation()
            self.left.setHeight() if isLeft else self.right.setHeight()
        self.setHeight()

def printNodes(self):
    if self.left is not sentinel:
        self.left.printNodes()
    print(self)
    if self.right is not sentinel:
        self.right.printNodes()


def setHeight(self):
    self.height = max(self.left.height, self.right.height) + 1

def rotateRight(self):
    new_root = self.left
    new_left_sub = new_root.right
    old_root = self
    self = new_root
    old_root.left = new_left_sub
    new_root.right = old_root

def rotateLeft(self):
    new_root = self.right
    new_left_sub = new_root.left
    old_root = self
    self = new_root
    old_root.right = new_left_sub
    new_root.left = old_root

def doubleRotateRight(self):
    return

def doubleRotateLeft(self):
    return

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.data)

class binaryTree:

def __init__(self):
    self.root = sentinel

def add(self, data):
    print("Before adding", data)
    self.printAll()
    if self.root is sentinel:
        self.root = Node(data)
    else:
        self.root.addNode(data)


def printAll(self):
    if self.root is sentinel:
        print("Empty tree")
    else:
        self.root.printNodes()

if __name__ == '__main__':
b = binaryTree()
b.add(1)
b.add(22)
b.add(4)
b.add(26)
b.add(13)
b.add(3)
b.add(14)
b.add(6)
b.add(13)
b.add(5)
b.add(36)
b.add(43)
b.add(5)
for i in range(1, 20):
    b.add(i)
b.printAll()
```

Comment: Exactly where is your code failing?

Comment: Have you tried just replacing `self.data`.

Comment: my code falls when I am swaping nodes, I am doing something wrong. I am not sure if swaping data is enough because anyway you have to swap children

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your nodes contain a link to the parent (the root having itself as a parent). Then its easy:

```
def rotateLeft(self):
    new_root = self.right
    new_left_sub = new_root.left
    old_root = self

    self.parent.right = new_root #assuming self is a right child
    old_root.right = new_left_sub
    new_root.left = old_root
```

My code may not be correct, I can't test it right now, but the idea is: have the nodes keep a reference to the parent.

Some reference: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/AVLTreeImplementation.html

Comment: but what if I do not keep parent reference? And what if self is a root and has not got a parent?

Comment: The parent of the root is the root itself (will reference itself), thus that code will work just fine.
If you don't want to sue parent references you have two options: either find the parent by a DFS (bad idea) or move the data to maintain the AVL property (more tedious than using the parent...)